# How can I find the FormResponse response which caused the Google Form script to trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I need to find the response in `FormResponse` which caused the Google Form script to trigger.
Please note that using the last response sometimes is not correct when multiple submissions are made at the same time. I confirmed it through testing.

Comment: [e.response](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1)

Answer (score 0):

You'll get the  connected `response` passed to the function as a [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1).

```
function onFormSubmit(e/*event object passed, when triggered*/){
 const response/*The response this function is triggered with*/ = e.response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. e.response references all responses received and not just the specific response which triggered the event. How one can find the specific response which triggered the event?

Comment: @Julia It references the specific response triggered. If you get something else,  edit your question to show your code proving you get something else.